# How to delay before executing AsyncTask?

Tags: android

I'm trying to do some animations before executing AsyncTask, but it seems that the AsyncTask executed before finishing the ainmation (TranslateAnimation). is there anyway i can delay the AsyncTask untill the ainmation done ?

```
TranslateAnimation aim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, (y/4));
aim.setDuration(600);
aim.setFillAfter(true);
btn.startAnimation(aim);
new MyAsyncTask().execute(sTitle);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems You need to try [setAnimationListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.html#setAnimationListener%28android.view.animation.Animation.AnimationListener%29). Code would look like the following:

```
TranslateAnimation aim = new TranslateAnimation(0, 0, 0, (y/4));
aim.setDuration(600);
aim.setFillAfter(true);
aim.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(final Animation animation) {
        // TODO: autogenerated code
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(final Animation animation) {
        new MyAsyncTask().execute(sTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(final Animation animation) {
        // TODO: autogenerated code
    }
});
btn.startAnimation(aim);
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked ... also i tried to use handler to delay and it worked perfect too. Thank you

Comment: And how to make an Animation finish on asyncTask finish?

Comment: You can put Animation.cancel() call to AsyncTask.onPostExecute().

Comment: @Marek , "finish" like updaing the animation while executing doInBackground ? or just cancel a loop animation after finishing the execution ? if the second option i think sandrstar's answer is perfect..